# Test variable in a bash case statement

Tags: bash, shell-script

What I want is simply to do something if the first variable of the script is empty, in a case statement.

Unfortunately I spent yet a certain amount of time searching for the solution but didn't find it.

Here is my code:

```
case $1 in 
    [[ -z $1 ]]) echo "something" ;; 
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `test` command when using `case`, and don't need `case` when using `test`:

```
case $1 in 
  ("") echo "something" ;; 
esac
```

and:

```
[[ -z $1 ]] && echo "something"
```

or using old test `[...]` for portability:

```
[ -z "$1" ] && echo "something"
```

Comment: Thx a lot, it works now :p

Comment: @math Please note the double quotes with the "old" test. Some shells return an error when the variable after -z is empty unless you use the quotes.